# bootstrap-datepicker.js auto close and not greater than this month

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker as the date picker in my form in conjunction with Twitter Bootstrap, and I'm having trouble getting it to auto close, and for any month/year combination greater than current month/year to be selectable. I've gone over and over the documentation, but can't see to get it. Any assistance appreciated.

My form is below

```
<div class="control-group">
   <label class="control-label" for="CC_CARDEXPIRY"><strong>Card Expiry Month/Year</strong></label>
   <div class="controls">
      <div class="input-append date datepicker" id="CC_CARDEXPIRY" data-date="01/2014" data-date-format="mm/yyyy" data-date-viewmode="years" data-date-minviewmode="months">
         <input class="span6" name="CC_CARDEXPIRY" size="20" type="text" value="01/2015" readonly>
         <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
      </div>   
   </div>
</div>
```

and my Javascript currently is

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"</script>    
<script src="../js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
  $('#CC_CARDEXPIRY').datepicker();              
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, autoclose is false. You have to manually set it in the code as an option.

---

After playing with the datepicker, I found a way to do it without touching the autoclose:

I put this function above my call to the datepicker:

```
var popup =  function(){
    var d = $(this);
    d.datepicker('update', new Date.today().toString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
    .on('changeDate', function(ev){
        // do what you want here
        d.datepicker('hide');
    });
};
```

Then my call to the datepicker looks like this:

```
this.$('i.icon-calendar').datepicker().on('show', popup);
```

I would highly recommend using the code found [here](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) instead of the eycon version. It originally came from eycon, but the github repo maintained by eternicode has a greater following, which means if you find and report a bug, there's a greater chance it will get fixed. I'm not saying it's any easier to use, but there's more support.

Comment: Hmm I've looked through the docs on http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker and can't see an example on how to set this, do you mean I need to hack the bootstrap-datepicker.js ?

Comment: Hey @LJT, I modified my answer and now it includes a sort of hack to get it to close as well as a different source.